# How get text between two closed tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery solution

```
<pre><marker id="markerStart"></marker>
aaaaa
<span style='font-family:monospace;background-color:#a0a0a0;'>bbb</span>bb
cc<marker id="markerEnd"></marker>ccc
</pre>
```

How get text between `<marker>` tags? Should be the following result:
aaaaabbbbbcc

Example 2 (markerEnd inside SPAN tag):

```
<pre><marker id="markerStart"></marker>
aaaaa
<span style='font-family:monospace;background-color:#a0a0a0;'>b<marker id="markerEnd"></marker>bb</span>bb
ccccc
</pre>
```

expected result: aaaaab

Thanks.

Comment: I already have solution:

s = s + $('pre').html();
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('<marker id="marker">'));
s = s.replace(/&(lt|gt);/g, function (strMatch, p1){ return (p1 == "lt")? "<" : ">"; });
s = s.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
alert(s);

Answer (score 3):

You can get all elements between two nodes like this:

```
$('marker:first').nextUntil('marker').text()
```

However, since you need to include text nodes, you need to write

```
var contents = $('pre').contents(),
    start = contents.filter('marker:first'),
    end = start.nextAll('marker:first'),
    startIndex = contents.index(start),
    endIndex = contents.index(end);

alert(contents.filter(function(i) {
    return i > startIndex && i < endIndex;
}).text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/2jEps/

Comment: And as finishing touch, add `.replace(/\s+/g, '')` to the result to remove white space, so the result will literally be `"aaaaabbbbbcc"`, like the OP wants.

Comment: markerEnd can be anywhere inside <pre> tag. So, this example (markerEnd inside <span>) return empty string:
<pre><marker id="markerStart"></marker>
aaaaa
<span style='font-family:monospace;background-color:#a0a0a0;'>b<marker id="markerEnd"></marker>bb</span>bb
ccccc
</pre>

Comment: @Balamut: Then you'll need to recurse through the DOM tree, adding texts until you hit `markerEnd`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
function textBetween(id1, id2) {
    var node = document.getElementById(id1).nextSibling,
        text = ''; 

    while ( node && node.id !== id2 ) {
        text += node.textContent.trim();
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }

    return text;   
}
```

Call this to get your text:

```
textBetween('markerStart', 'markerEnd')
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/yxVxy/4/